# Converting multiple simple queries into a single one?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm new to SQL so things will have to be explained like I'm 5. I'm trying to figure out **how many people performed the event "clicked learn more" and then proceeded to perform the event "set trial status"**. I'm using Postgres so there is an additional `AND payload->>'status' = true` that I've left out to simplify it. Essentially I need the following psuedo-queries turned into a functional single query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT booking_id
FROM venue_events
WHERE name = 'clicked learn more'`;

SELECT count(*)
FROM venue_events
WHERE booking = booking_id AND name = 'set trial status' AND payload->>'status' = true;
```

How can I turn that into essentially one single SQL query, the second using the booking_ids from the first

Below is what the data looks like in the table.

[image: row layout]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I apologise. I don't have any sample data at this moment, this is part of the problem - I'm doing it as I'm going along. I'm writing an endpoint to fetch analytics for a feature that's currently being built.

Comment: However, each event will have `name, timestamp, payload`. The `payload` is jsonb. It's a very simple table with not many fields and that's why I thought this should be quite achieveable even with a dataset of 5 entries I could manually create to test it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added an image showing what this data would look like in the table. Also, what I want to achieve is in bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing table structures and sample data it's hard be completely certain, but if you want to get all the counts you mentioned in a comment to another answer, I think this query is what you need.

```
SELECT v1.booking_id AS booking_id,
       COUNT(v1.booking_id) AS Clicked_learn_more, 
       COUNT(v2.booking_id) AS Set_trial_status_true,
       COUNT(v3.booking_id) AS Completed_booking
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT booking_id 
      FROM venue_events 
      WHERE name='clicked learn more' AND payload->>'status' = true) v1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT booking_id 
           FROM venue_events 
           WHERE name='set trial status' AND payload->>'status' = true) v2
    ON v2.booking_id = v1.booking_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT booking_id 
           FROM venue_events 
           WHERE name='completed booking' AND payload->>'status' = true) v3
    ON v3.booking_id = v1.booking_id
GROUP BY v1.booking_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that has answered my original question and has successfully extended upon it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM venue_events
WHERE name = 'set trial status' 
AND booking_id IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT booking_id
    FROM venue_events
    WHERE name = 'clicked learn more'
)
AND payload->>'status' = true;
```

Comment: This is looking good so far, just doing some tests to make sure it's all good.

Comment: Hi @PepperPaige, is there any way that I can get each of those counts individually within this query? So that I could have the result like:


Clicked Learn More = 10
Set Trial Status True = 4
Completed Booking = 1

Since I'd currently have to do 3 queries to get these individual counts, each query growing in size.

Comment: Sure - you'd probably want to use GROUP BY along with COUNT.  I'd recommend checking other questions on stack overflow that probably already cover that well, or ask an additional question if you find you need more info.

Comment: You need `IN` not `=` and you can drop the `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0):

i think you need group by name

```
SELECT name ,count(*)
FROM venue_events
WHERE   payload->>'status' = true
group by name
```